# Is C# used in iOS and Android projects created by VS2017?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I've recently started learning about `Xamarin` so please bear with me. I'm not sure if this is an obvious question

Creating a cross-platform mobile app in `VS2017` will create 3 projects: `Xamarin.Forms`, iOS, Android.

So in my `Xamarin.Forms` project I was able to add a map to my Form, and now I can see the map in my Android emulator. That works great. I havent't touched the other two projects.

Now I have to add some functionality that's native of each platform, so I would need to go, for example, to the `Android project` to add the widgets, logic, etc.

Is C# used in these native projects or do I need to learn a new language?

I'm asking because `Android Studio` uses `java` and iOS uses `Objective C`, so I'm not sure if I need to learn these languages for cha

Comment: Here is a official document about custom map in xamarin forms can be refer to.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Microsoft website for [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) it answers your question then and there;

> Xamarin.Forms expose a complete cross-platform UI toolkit for .NET developers. Build fully-native Android, iOS, and Universal Windows Platform apps using C# in Visual Studio.

But even [F#](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/01/01/build-xamarin-apps.aspx) is available as an option.

As far as your platform-specific question goes there is a whole separate guide that teaches you how and when you need platform specific code which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/)

> Is C# used in these native projects or do I need to learn a new language?
>   I'm asking because Android Studio uses java and iOS uses Objective C, so I'm not sure if I need to learn these languages.

Yes, that is the whole point for the Xamarin native and Xamarin.Forms framework that pure C#/F# developers can become mobile application developers without learning a new language.So existing .Net teams can execute mobile projects.

But in some cases, you might have to convert native `Java` and `Objective-C` code to `C#` so it's always better if you have a basic level of understanding in them.

I will suggest you read the [Code Sharing Strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing) available in Xamarin Forms before deciding which method do you wanna follow: I personally and the Community prefers using The `.Net Standard` methodology to share the code you can choose for yourself.

Good luck with your future endeavours and feel free to revert in case of further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all Xamarin projects use C# (or F#).  You do not need to use java or Obj-C/Swift, although there are ways to incorporate native libraries written in those languages into Xamarin projects.

Xamarin has a entire section of docs on how to incorporate [platform specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/) behavior into a Xamarin Forms app.